# Is there more than one provisioning technology named fog?

Tags: mysql, php, puppet, cloud, rubygems

I have a puppet installation in which I tried to check the fog version (for cloud provisioning), but I got no response so I assumed it was not installed. I need fog in order to utilize the vmware cloning ability of puppet. In any case, it seems fog is installed via ruby gems, but when I looked at fog.io it was not similar to the fog wiki page I saw in which php/apache/mysql, etc., was involved and no mention of a .fog file. Ergo, I am trying to make sure I am installing the right fog for my puppet configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use puppet to [provision servers in VMWare](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/cloudprovisioner_vmware.html). "Cloning" is not the right word for this; "provisioning" is. You need to install [Fog](http://fog.io/), a ruby cloud services library. This has nothing to do with [FOG Project](http://www.fogproject.org/), a computer cloning solution. My guess is that you are confusing the two.

Comment: yes, that is exactly it. I essentially installed both. I tried to install Fog, the ruby cloud services library by upgrading my ruby installation, but the version of Ruby that came with puppet wouldn't be overwritten so I couldn't upgrade Ruby in order to get Fog. In any case, you more or less answered my question, but if you have any further input that would be appreciated. thanks.